# Using a tabbar controller with monotouch.dialog

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, monotouch.dialog

I am trying to basically the same as poupou has shown on this previous SO post

[Tab Bar at the Bottom with MonoTouch.Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297348/tab-bar-at-the-bottom-with-monotouch-dialog)

My question is what template do I use to get started with this? I have tried each of the templates and none of the inherit from the UINavigationController

Can anyone point me (a complete mono useless one) in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is what template do I use to get started with this? I have tried each of the templates and none of the inherit from the UINavigationController

There are too many possibilities to offer templates for every one of them (it would be more confusing than helping).

Most people using [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) are coding their UI *from scratch*, i.e. no Interface Builder, no template, just plain old code.

You can find several samples that uses MonoTouch.Dialog on github (e.g. it's own [Sample](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/tree/master/Sample), [TweetStation](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TweetStation), [Touch.Unit](https://github.com/spouliot/Touch.Unit)...) or in blogs or [videos](http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/02/10/easily-create-ios-user-interfaces-with-monotouch-dialog/). If you hit a specific issue then you can ask for it on stackoverflow.

> Can anyone point me (a complete mono useless one) in the right direction

See Xamarin's [tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/MonoTouch.Dialog#Using_UINavigationController) on MonoTouch.Dialog.

Comment: Thanks poupou, I think I was trying to make the task harder then actually was